# Right way of getting degrees of vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose I have the following list of nodes:

- A E G
- A E H
- A F G
- A F H
- B E G
- B E H
- B F G
- B F H
- C F
- C E
- D G
- D H

Every line indicates the connections between those nodes. So there is a connection between `A` and `E`, `E` and `G`, `A` and `G`.

This is how the graph looks like:

[image]

I now want to compute the degrees of all nodes.

There are several option:

- Count the occurrences in the list
- `A, B, C, D: 4`
- `E, F, G, H: 5`
- `C, D: 2`
- Count all combinations
- `A-E, A-G, A-E, A-H, A-F, A-G, A-F, A-H --> A: 8`

What is the right approach?

Also, I want the relative degrees of them, so a number in the interval of `0` an `1`.

So I assume, that would be $$\frac{\mathrm{degree}}{\mathrm{total\:\#\:of\:degrees}} \implies A= \frac{4}{32}=0.125$$

Comment: I do not follow this. The degree of a node is the number of edges it has. A has edges to C,E,F,G so it has degree 4. D has edges to G,H, so it has degree 2.

Comment: Both options are obviously wrong: for the second degree of $A$ is actually $4$, for the first, after removing $(A,F,H)$ from the list degree of $A$ would be still $4$.

Comment: We have lines `A E G` and `A E H`, so does that mean we have two edges AE?

Comment: As I understand, you have a list of cliques such that their unity is graph itself. Is it given that cliques are maximal?

Comment: @Abstraction: Why are both options wrong? In my first option, the degree of `A` is actually `4`.

Comment: @user1170330 Reread my comment please. Your first option would give answer $3$ for list without $(A,F,H)$ while degree of $A$ would still be $4$ (since it would still be connected to $E,F,G,H$).

Comment: I got confused right at the start when you said "the following list of nodes". This is a list of nodes: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H. Those are the nodes. AEG is not a node. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

There is very easy way: for $N$ vertices, create [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) $N \times N$ filled with $0$'s and then for each clique set corresponding elements to 1. For each vertex, degree will  be sum of rows (or columns). For your example, with vertices ordered $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H$ adjacency matrix will be:
$$\pmatrix{
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 }$$

This approach requires $O(N^2)$ memory and up to $O(N^4)$ operations in worst cases.

Slightly smarter approach: for each vertex $V$, go through clique list; for every clique containing $V$ add to the set of connected vertices all other vertices of the clique. Count elements in the set. $O(N)$ memory, $O(N^4)$ time. Essentially this is computing adjacency matrix one row at a time.

For big graphs we may try this:

1. Divide vertices in two sets (simple way: first $N/2$ and second $N/2$).
2. Find the biggest clique $C$ ("pivot clique") of size $N_c$ containing vertices from both sets (if no such clique exists, divide the list into two and repeat algorithm from step 1 for each new list separately).
3. Divide other cliques into containing vertices from $C$ ("reduce list") and not ("remainder list").
4. Add $N_c-1$ to degrees of all vertices from $C$.
5. For each clique in the reduce list, for each vertex of $C$ containing in that clique add non-$C$ vertices of the clique to sets corresponding to $C$-vertices.
6. For each vertex of $C$ add size of corresponding set to its degree and 1 to degree of all vertices in that set.
7. For each clique of the reduce list, remove $C$ vertices from it and add what's left to the remainder list (if only one vertex remains or we found that there is a clique in remainder list which includes ours, remove it instead).
8. Repeat from 2. with remainder list (unless it's empty).

Taking your graph as an example:

1. Sets are $(A,C,E,F), (B,D,G,H)$. Initial degrees are $(A:0,B:0,C:0,D:0,E:0,F:0,G:0,H:0)$.

2a. Pivot clique is $(A,E,G)$.

3. Reduce list: $(A,F,G)$, $(A,E,H)$, $(A,F,H)$, $(B,E,G)$, $(B,E,H)$, $(B,F,G)$, $(C,E)$, $(D,G)$. Remainder list: $(B,F,H)$, $(C,F)$, $(D,H)$.
4. Degrees are $(A:2,B:0,C:0,D:0,E:2,F:0,G:2,H:0)$.
5. Sets are $A: \{F,H\}$, $E: \{B,C,H\}$, $G: \{B,D,F\}$.
6. Degrees are $(A:4,B:2,C:1,D:1,E:5,F:2,G:5,H:2)$.
7. Remainder list: $(B,F,H)$, $(C,F)$, $(D,H)$, $(F,H)$(removed), $(B,H)$(removed), $(B,F)$(removed).

2b. Pivot clique is $(B,F,H)$.

3. Reduce list: $(C,F),(D,H)$. Remainder list: (empty).
4. Degrees are $(A:4,B:4,C:1,D:1,E:5,F:4,G:5,H:4)$.
5. Sets are $B: \{\}$, $F: \{C\}$, $H: \{D\}$.
6. Degrees are $(A:4,B:4,C:2,D:2,E:5,F:5,G:5,H:5)$.
7. Remainder list: (empty).

Result - degrees are $(A:4,B:4,C:2,D:2,E:5,F:5,G:5,H:5)$. This algorithm requires $O(N^3)$ memory and possibly up to $O(N^5)$ time in worst case, but can be potentially very effective if it manages to "cut" the graph in half quickly enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing. As one of the commenters points out, it looks a lot like you have a list of [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique) - that is, sets of nodes all connected to each other within the set.

The *degree* of a node is just the number of neighbours it has (or edges connected to it) and your graph seems to have {5: [E, F, G, H], 4: [A, B], 2: [C, D] } based on the diagram. I've re-drawn it a bit more symmetrically :

[image]

looks a bit nicer, I think.
Finally, I'm not sure what you mean by 'relative degree' - do you mean the sum of the degrees of the nodes in the clique divided by the number of nodes in the clique?

Comment: Yes. I want to be able to compare nodes of different cliques to each other. So having 5 neighbors in a clique of 10 nodes should have a higher degree, than in a clique of 100 nodes.  
Is there such a concept?

Comment: @user1170330 ah i begin to see now. you want a sort of 'clique degree' which is the size of the set of adjacent nodes in the same clique? except that you seem to be counting the number of cliques a node is a member of - or 'clique contribution'. note also that each node in a clique has the same number of neighbours in that clique, by definition!